# 2010 Yamaha VStar 250 Won’t Start

Tags: motorcycle, yamaha

I bought a bike on CL a week or so ago and after some fresh gas and a new battery it was running well again. I was reminding myself how to ride when i stalled the engine and lost power. Having trouble finding neutral, and the bike won’t start with the clutch engaged. Lights still work like normal, but the thing won’t even turn over. Am i just being an idiot and starting it wrong, or is it something wrong with the bike?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Does it make any sound when you try to start it, like trying to but it does not ignite or just doesn't make any sound?

Comment: First check you have found neutral, then are there any lights, then do they dim when you operate the start button?